# What is USH.HTML and why do some robot try to access it?

Tags: robots.txt, logging, web-crawlers

I have been getting quite a few hits on my webservers for the resource `/USH.HTML`. I have never hosted this file, and do not know what it is.

Is this a type of `robots.txt` file or something specific to a certain CMS?

***UPDATE***

I found out the answer, and it is a similar Japanese website that has a domain very similar to ours, but with a hyphen in the name instead. I guess all the 404s are due to a typo on the referring link.

Comment: A quick Google search didn't turn up anything for me. It might be a file that can be exploited or confirm to a hacker that a specific software package is installed and now that they know it is there they can try to exploit it. Just speculation, though. That's why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it definitely a bot? Do you have a user-agent? And is there a referer [sic] header for those requests?

A Google search doesn't bring up anything remotely significant so I don't think it's related to robots.txt, nor anything like a bot polling for security flaws.

It is likely to be something simple like a mistyped link to your site - for example you have a page "usb.html" or "rush.html", or perhaps a site with a similar domain name has the page "ush.html".

Comment: Yahoo, MSN, Baidu and a couple of unknowns from Japan have all tried to access it. The file has *never* existed and is not similar to any other filename or resource on the site.

Comment: Then perhaps it's just someone fooling around, OR another site with a similar domain (@DisgruntledGoat) which has the page "ush.html".